# OAuthMissingForThisService Authentication for this service requires OAuth

Tags: office365

Why are we no longer able to query the office365 REST URL to get messages?

Last week I was able to read message by going to URL:    https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages

and now I can only get this response:

```
{"error":{"code":"OAuthMissingForThisService","message":"Authentication for this service requires OAuth: outlook.office.com."}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0 doesn't support Basic auth as OAuth is the recommended auth mechanism, but you can continue to use https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0 if you need to keep using Basic auth.

Comment: Merci Venkat! :)  You saved my day!

Comment: You saved my day as well:)

Comment: You've saved my day and this is probably one of the best tips I've ever seen on Stackoverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i'm unable to edit my question to add the example I promised to Thomas so here it is 
(see more references : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations)

`

```
//GET method for REST API
function ews_get($odata_command)
{
    //$URL = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/Me';  //doesn't work anymore
    $URL = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Me'; //Thanks Venkat :)

    //concatenation of the command url
    $URL .= $odata_command;

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,             // return web page content
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,             // follow redirections
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,             // set referer on redirections
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,               // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,               // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,            // Disabled SSL Cert checks
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => EWS_USERNAME . ':' . EWS_PASSWORD, //see constants
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_BASIC,   //Basic authentication 
    );

    $ch = curl_init($URL);

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    $objResult = json_decode(curl_exec( $ch ));

    curl_close( $ch );

    return $objResult;
}


//Return a folder information for an Inbox subfolder named $displayName
function getInboxChildFolderByDisplayName($displayName)
{
    //NOTE DEV: The $ sign is not correctly interpreted in a double quote string in php
    //NOTE DEV: The ' in the url was replaced by %27
    $results = ews_get('/Folders(\'Inbox\')/ChildFolders?$filter=DisplayName%20eq%20%27' . $displayName . '%27');

    $arrFolderInfo = $results->value;

    //return the first folder info
    return $arrFolderInfo[0];
}


//Get messages from the folder id
function getMessagesFromFolderId($folderId = 'Inbox')
{
    $objResult = ews_get("/Folders('" . $folderId . "')/Messages");

    return $objResult->value;
}


/////////////
//Example 
/////////////
$folder_id = getInboxChildFolderByDisplayName('MySubFolder')->Id;

$arrMessage = getMessagesFromFolderId($folder_id);

print_r($arrMessage);

//Have fun!
?>
```

`